# Script that removes undesired characters from variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script that sets a variable. It is usually an URL that has been copied from a HTML file and then that variable is used.

I take the copied text/clipboard contents using `xclip -out` and set that as a variable - let's say `$CLIP`. However, the copied URL can sometimes have unwanted characters, such as `` ",',` `` etc. I want the script to replace all of those with spaces.

Comment: Please check my edits and make sure they've not changed the intent of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the copied URL can sometimes have unwanted characters, such as `` ",',` ``
>   etc. I want the script to replace all of those with spaces.

You could use `sed` for this.

If your `$url` variable looks something like this:

```
echo $url 
http://1f,oo"2b`a'r.com
```

This `sed` replaces all the "unwanted" chars with spaces:

```
echo $url | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9:/\.]/ /g'
http://1f oo 2b a r.com
```

Comment: this will break if the final url parsed needs symbols like & ; %

Comment: Then simply add those to the valid chars in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

many ways to do this

use the correct hex codes for your own case

```
clean_url="$(echo ${dirty_url} | sed 's/[\x20-\x2D]/ /g')"
```

then i would run it through to check to see if you have multiple spaces and reduce that to one space with somethign like

```
clean_url=$(sed 's/  */ /g' <<< ${clean_url})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) after enabling [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)

```
CLIP=$'http://abc\".x\'y`.com'
printf '%s\n' "$CLIP"
http://abc".x'y`.com
chars_to_remove=("'" '"' '`') #set characters to remove into an array
chars_to_remove=$(IFS='|'; printf '+(%s)' "${chars_to_remove[*]}") #assemble in extglob format
printf '%s\n' $chars_to_remove
+('|"|`)
printf '%s\n' "${CLIP//${chars_to_remove}/ }"
http://abc .x y .com
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified Bash Parameter Expansion:

```
root@debian:# CLIP=$'http://abc\".x\'y`.com';cleanclip=$(echo ${CLIP//[\'\`\"]});echo $cleanclip
#Output:
http://abc.xy.com
```

PS: Pattern to be removed is inside [] and chars are escaped.

See [Bash manual , para 3.5.3](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC31) about *${parameter/pattern/string}*